# How can I find why I'm using so much data on mobile network?

Tags: 3g, data-monitoring

According to my provider, I've used 6.8MB of data within 3 days.

The thing is, I don't know how. I've installed DroidWall and WiSync and only used Waze (a navigation app). I installed Traffic Monitor which shows Waze using less than 800KB and other apps even less (some of them used traffic before I setup DroidWall)

Any clues as to what is using 6MB??

Comment: It would make sense for a navigation app to use more than 800 KB. I would suspect Traffic Monitor is inaccurate, personally.

Comment: Why should it use so much? I predownload all maps. It syncs traffic data, that's it. And I've used it for a total of maybe 2 hours.

Comment: pre-downloading the maps is going to use data. And even if you predownload the maps, it will still use the network to check if your route needs changing. Plus there are other apps that will check and sync information. if you want to ensure that you dont use any data when using the navigation, you can try to disable the data network.

Comment: preloading over wifi... checking if route needs changing should not take 800000 bytes. something is definitely using data, the question is how to find it.

Comment: Try [My Data Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&feature=search_result).  It says it can report usage per application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[My Data Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&feature=search_result) is a free app available in the android market which will aid you in catering your needs. It will give you a detailed statistics of which app/service used how much data.

Edit : did not notice this was answered in the comments already.